# Error 405 (Method not allowed)

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, iis-express

I'm trying to post a form using angularJs with the $http.post method. But whenever i execute this function it gives me this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
I have no clue what to do.
(Im using visual studio 2015)

```
 $scope.addRow = function () {
        var parameter = JSON.stringify({ id: 99, first_name: $scope.firstName, last_name: $scope.lastName, email: $scope.email, country: $scope.country, phone_number: $scope.phoneNumber });
        $http.post('MOCK_DATA.json', parameter).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Comment: the first parameter of `$http.post` is the URL you want to post to.  are you trying to post directly into a file?

Comment: yes, but i don't know what to do

Answer (score 2):

You have a file : `'MOCK_DATA.json'`.
The only thing you are allowed to do with this file is retrieving it from your client. (Http Verb 'GET').

If you want to update this file to add values, you must create a controller that will receive your object. Inside this controller you will have to write new lines into your file.

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you mean. I'm kinda new to all of this

Comment: A website, with data that can be updated needs a front-end (the thing you do with angular, html,...) and a back-end. The back-end must be responsible for handling the requests of the front end. I suggest you to learn the basics of c# and asp.net if you want a webserver with Visual Studio. eg : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 0):

I think I 've often had this problem because the parameters of the query that does not pass. Try something like this:

```
$http({
     url: '/api/customers/GetFilteredList',
     params: { 
        'lastName': lastName,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'address': address,
        'town': town,
        'zipCode': zipCode,
        'skip': skip,
        'take': take 
     } 
 });
```